# ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I am an absolute beginner to storm. This is an example from getting started with storm (book). The wordcounter example . I am using storm in local and when i run this example using maven i am getting this error.
Maven command use :

```
[knk@kinock Storm-Starter]$mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="src/main/resources/words.txt"
```

### This is the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at spouts.WordReader.open(WordReader.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3430$fn__3445.invoke(executor.clj:504) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__444.invoke(util.clj:401) ~[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
5608 [Thread-22-word-reader] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor - 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at spouts.WordReader.open(WordReader.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3430$fn__3445.invoke(executor.clj:504) ~  [storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__444.invoke(util.clj:401) ~[storm-core- 0.9.0.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
5610 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor __system:[-1 -1]
5618 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: __system __system  ["startup"]
5619 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks __system: [-1 -1]
5624 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor __system:[-1 -1]
5629 [Thread-24-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt __system:(-1)
5638 [Thread-24-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt __system:(-1)
5668 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor __acker:[1 1]
5670 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: __acker __system ["startup"]
5671 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks __acker:[1 1]
5672 [Thread-22-word-reader] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
5678 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Timeouts disabled for executor __acker:[1 1]
5679 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor __acker: [1 1]
```

**This is the Block of code raising exception .. 62nd line is marked with comment .**

```
public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        try {

            //this.collector = collector;
            this.context = context;
            this.fileReader = new  FileReader(conf.get("wordsFile").toString());//exception is raised here. 62nd line
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file ["+conf.get("wordFile")+"]");
            }
        this.collector = collector;
    }
```

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: @user2720864
Hi there . This link has the entire code . Under spouts the java class named WordReader is raising the exception . The above quoted block of code is from this class . Thank you ...

https://github.com/storm-book/examples-ch02-getting_started/tree/master/src/main/java

Comment: wanted to see the main class where you are building the `topology` object .. and also what you are putting inside the `Config` object

Comment: This is the main class ..

https://github.com/storm-book/examples-ch02-getting_started/blob/master/src/main/java/TopologyMain.java

Comment: this looks odd, I've tried but not able to reproduce the same issue, for me its just working fine .. can u try to run a very simple topology and see if everything is fine.. just create a maven project along with the storm dependency (if you have problem doing it then let me know, I can provide the pom.xml sample) .. also have you tried running it from the IDE ? the line `[storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:na]` looks strange and it seems something is wrong .. might need to dig more in that ... it should be simple enough to run a basic storm sample ..

Comment: @user2720864 it was my fault . I started using java from last four months . The issue was i should have been giving the full path to the file i.e from root. then in pom.xml my maven compiler version was different . thank you so much for helping .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[knk@kinock Storm-Starter]$mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TopologyMain" -Dexec.args="src/main/resources/words.txt"

In the above command the complete path to the file should be given or else java cant find the path.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason could be it is not able to read the `wordsFile` entry from the `Config` object .. e.g if you have some thing like 
`FileReader(conf.get("wordsFile").toString());`  
and then if you use `conf.put("SomeOtherWordsFile", ..)` 
then it will try to find the file path location (inside the `spout's` open method) form the `conf` object by searching the key `wordsFile` which is actually not present

Comment: in my main class conf.put is like this 
conf.put("wordsFile", args[0]);